# Remix + Metamask temporarily OFF?

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask

Helloo, it is 02.02.2022, 19h (central European time) and I am trying to run all possible contracts in Remix and nothing is working, contracts that I had already successfully run before. I tried closing and opening again, restarting the computer, disconnecting and reconnecting metamask...

Either I receive "Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address." in the terminal, or I receive a pop up window with the following message: "Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? The execution failed due to an exception. Reverted"
One friend of mine confirmed the same situation, none of his contracts are deploying. Is this happening to someone else? Thank you in advance for all your answers.

Comment: Is metamask connected to Remix?

Comment: yes, sure it is.

Comment: Can you share the contract and a screenshot of the Remix page?

Comment: Hi LauraMaria! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Please provide more details about the contracts and network used, mainnet, rinkeby, bsc, polygon, etc.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your interaction. I have created another post with more accurate information. I think I really found a BUG. If you have 5 minutes please take a look at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/120708/remix-does-not-switch-address . Kind regards